# How to get the latest value to a state from a redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am fairly new to Redux, I'm using the `react-redux` package and trying to implement a simple feature (although I know this can be handled via local state), where whatever you type in the input should be displayed below between the `<p></p>` tags.

Below is the code:

[image: Edit 73zq1yl2r1]

I'm a bit skeptical about line 62, the way I am accessing the latest state to print out, is it the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Start by the way. I think you have little bit complicated the state part. I modified it for you and also removed `bind` keyword which i feel not required if you use latest JS lang spec.

I have used `Object.assign` just to prevent the state object mutation. Usually this is avoided by using [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) ***(Please read the doc)***

```
// Reducer.
const updateReducer = (state = {text:''}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TEXT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { text: action.text });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    text: state.text
  };
};
```

And Render method:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={(...arg) => this.changeText(...arg)} />
        <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Whats wrong with your initial code?**

You were storing all the text in an array for each key stroke alongside with updated and growing text. At render just display the last one *(Created unwanted copies in the array which is never used)* and omit other array values. Instead just replace the old value with current incoming value.

Your Forked code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/13nyk87k6q)

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: thank you! You've explained it wonderfully and that has helped a lot!